# Decomposition into generalized eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I would be very grateful if someone would check the following proof for me. I came up with it as an alternative to the longer proof in the book I am reading.

> > **Theorem.** Let $V\neq\{0\}$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over an algebraically closed field $F$. Suppose $\alpha\in\text{End}(V)$ with distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k \in F$. Let $E_j=\ker(\alpha-\lambda_j\iota)^{m_j}$ where $m_j$ is the multiplicity of $\lambda_j$ as a root of the min. poly. $m_\alpha$.
> >     $$V=E_1\oplus\ldots\oplus E_k.$$
>
> *Proof.* We first show that the sum $E_1+\ldots+E_k$ is direct. Indeed, suppose we have
>   \begin{equation*}
> v_1+\ldots+v_k=0
> \tag{$*$}
> \end{equation*}
>   where each $v_j \in E_j$. Write $m_\alpha(t)=(t-\lambda_j\iota)^{m_j}q_j(t)$ where $q_j(t)$ is coprime to $(t-\lambda_j\iota)^{m_j}$.
>
> By the Euclidean algorithm, there exist $f(t),g(t) \in F[t]$ such that 
>   $$1=f(t)(t-\lambda_j)^{m_j}+g(t)q_j(t).$$
>
> Applying $q_j(\alpha)$ to $(*)$ we obtain $q_j(\alpha)(v_j)=0\;$ i.e. $v_j \in \ker q_j(\alpha)$ and so it follows that
>   $$v_j=f(\alpha)(\alpha-\lambda_j\iota)^{m_j}(v_j)+g(\alpha)q_j(\alpha)(v_j)=0.$$
>   Since $j$ was arbitrary it follows that the sum is direct.
>
> We now show that $V=E_1+\ldots+E_k$. As the sum is direct, we have
>   $$\dim(E_1+\ldots+E_k)=\dim E_1+\ldots+\dim E_k.$$
>   Observe that $\dim E_j = \text{null}(\alpha-\lambda_j\iota)^{m_j}$ and so
>   $$\dim E_1+\ldots+\dim E_k \geq \text{null}\left(\prod_j(\alpha-\lambda_j\iota)^{m_j}\right)=\text{null}(m_\alpha(\alpha))=\dim V.$$
>   It follows, by dimension, that $E_1+\ldots+E_k$ is all of $V$. //

Comment: What exactly do you not understand in this proof?

Comment: It's not that I don't understand it but that I would quite like someone to check it for me. I have now clarified this in the original post :)

Comment: Ok. There is nothing wrong with this proof. It is very clever to split up the minimal polynomial into maximal coprime factors instead of irreducible ones. That way the structure of the Young blocks is avoided. Nice work!

Comment: Just wondering if you remember what book this is from? I've been trying to find a reference to this result to not avail for a long time!